# Polymer attribute directive

Tags: javascript, polymer

Is there any way to achieve angularjs attribute directive in polymer. I want to call a function based on a particular attribute attached to any element.

[This](http://jsbin.com/wafugipedo/edit?html,output) is what works for me right now, but this is very non-generic.
Is there any easier way to extend behavior of elements using just attributes like

```
<paper-input behavior="custom-behavior" custom-behavior-attribute="some-data"></paper-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have started building an app in Polymer which was already done in Angular. Even I had the same query running on my mind and I found this link related to this topic and it says Polymer's behavior is the equivalent to Angular's attribute directive.

https://plus.google.com/+JustinFagnani/posts/EjdR14bA7Dj

It will be useful if someone can confirm that there are no other approach available to achieve the same.